# Error in if else statement using to assign flag in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, tidyverse, lubridate

Any suggestions to fix the following code that would assign either `1` or `0` to particular months of column `BFlag`?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1928-01-01"), 
                      to = as.Date("1930-12-31"), 
                      by = "day")) %>%  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
  mutate(BFlag = ifelse(Month == c(1,2,3,11,12),1,ifelse(Month == c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10),0)))
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? background/what has been tried/what does the current endproduct look like, what should it be?
At this moment you have a subject that is a question and a different question with code. There does not seem to be a clear problem or focus to your post. Please remember that people on SO love to help. But they do need enough information. Nobody will go through a trial and error process to maybe give the right answer to a unclear quesiton.

Comment: I think you want to use ifelse(Month %in% c(1,2,3,11,12),...) instead of == if you are trying to match to a vector rather than an individual value.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed my code and its giving me the answer i was looking for. Thanks to all who were looking at it. posted the answer as it may help someone else looking at similar problem.

```
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("1928-01-01"), 
                      to = as.Date("2009-12-31"), 
                      by = "day")) %>%  separate(Date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day")) %>% 
  mutate(BFlag = ifelse(Month %in% c("01","02","03","11","12"),1,0))
```

Comment: what was the issue?